# Keep Flutter layout LTR while using RTL language

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using 'easy_localization' flutter plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) for translating. I'm working on Arabic and English language.

By default when user change to Arabic, layout changes to RTL. But in some places, I wanted to keep the layout LTR.

Eg: 3 widgets in a ROW() A, B, C and when user change to Arabic it changes to C, B, A. But I wanted it to be A, B, C even user changes to Arabic. But in some places, it should be C, B, A.

Any solutions?

NOTE: I tried translation without a plugin following https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization but it is working same as above plugin

Comment: Have you tried changing `textDirection` property of a row?

Comment: getting this error when I used 'textDirection' ==> Error: Getter not found: 'rtl'. textDirection: TextDirection.rtl ==> this error appear ONLY if I import above flutter plugin

Comment: That's probably an error caused by intl package. Use this: `import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;` If it's not the intl package then use an alias for the error causing package.

Comment: I have moved the package logic to a different class and use "textDirection: TextDirection.ltr" where necessary. And it works :)

Comment: i have the same issue but with an SVG image and a Row how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`TextDirection` is offered by `intl` and `dart:ui` package. You want to use the enum from ui package, so hide the enum from intl package.

```dart
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart' hide TextDirection;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use "textDirection: TextDirection.ltr" for ROW() got following error.

Getter not found: 'rtl'. textDirection: TextDirection.rtl

And the above error appears ONLY if I import ==> 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart' on the same class

So I have created a separate class and use this package. Now I can use "textDirection: TextDirection.ltr" where I wanted to make component LTR even for Arabic